# ArcMap Add-In Not Updating To Latest Version

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, add-in, update

I'm having an issue that I haven't experienced before with ArcMap Add-Ins and I'm hoping someone out there has experienced this and knows of a solution.

We have an add-in build in VB.NET that is used by multiple users in my office. It is stored in a central location that we all have access to and each person who needs to use it has that folder added to their Add-In Manager. That way any needed updates can be made and everyone gets the latest copy every time they open ArcMap.

That has worked well until today. One user in particular can't seem to get the updated version. Even though the Add-In Manager shows the correct version when he goes to use the add-in it is clearly an old version because it doesn't have the latest change made to the code. Everyone else (pointed to the exact same folder) gets the latest version. We even removed the folder from the Add-In Manager and manually installed the add-in. Same thing. He always gets an old version no matter what we do.

Is there some type of cache I'm not aware of that might be holding onto the old one and tricking ArcMap into thinking it has all the updates?

Comment: We have had this problem too - and for the moment the only workaround is to delete the addin folder in the Assembly Cache folder for the problematic addin.  I have opened a case with ESRI - I won't hold my breath....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes there is a cache on the local machine.  At version 10.1 it is:

```
C:\Users\user name\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.1\AssemblyCache
```

In the AssemblyCache folder will be a folder for each add-in ArcMap has loaded. The folders are named with a long alpha-numeric that won't make any sense, but if you click into these folders you will see .dll, .pdb, and .xml files that have the same name as the add in. Simply delete the folder within the AssemblyCache folder that holds the add-in you want to be updated properly, and restart ArcMap.

Note that a few of these folders you need to click through are hidden, so you'll have to make sure you can see hidden folders.

Incidently, I also have a user who occasionally has this same issue, and I have no idea why it happens or how to prevent it from re-occuring.

Comment: That did it! I knew it had to be hanging onto an old version somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: Just as an FYI I'm in 10.2 and couldn't see the AssemblyCache folder even with hiden files and folders shown. I had to manually enter the path in the address bar and the folder opened fine --- In case anyone else tries this solution and can't find the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should try deleting the Normal.mxt file on their computer.

Go to:

```
C:\Users\Name\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcMap\Templates
```

and delete the Normal.mxt file.

This will remove all toolbars/customization from ArcMap.

Here's a little more [information](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00v000000005000000) from ESRI.