# Arcgis Addin don't upgrade

Tags: arcobjects, add-in

I am try to upgrade Addin for ArcGIS finish to install new upgrade but Arcgis run the old one I am finish to remove and install still I see version 1 not version 2

How can I fix this are any temp folder I can delete ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find and delete the Addins for ESRI at this location.

C:\Users\yourusername\Documents\ArcGIS\AddIns.

You also need to have your ESRI product closed when installing or reinstalling addins.

Comment: Finish to Delete Addins folder still run old version
then I found this in the forum and delete the addinn there and the new version  works http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131848/arcmap-add-in-not-updating-to-latest-version