# Lost ArcMap Add-in Toolbar Built with ArcObjects SDK in .NET and Problem with AssemblyCache folder and ArcGIS Cache Manager

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, .net, add-in

Our organization manages an ArcMap 10.6.1 add-in written using the ArcObjects SDK for .NET Framework 4.7.2. We publish the add-in file to a server folder. We edited the registry to make ArcMap look for the add-in in the server folder.

`REG ADD HKLM\Software\WOW6432Node\ESRI\Desktop10.6\Settings\AddInFolders /v "server_path_to_add_in_file" /t REG_SZ`

The problem is that a handful, but not most, user machines lose the toolbar in ArcMap every time we publish an updated add-in to the server folder, and the user has to either reboot their machine or ctrl-alt-delete and find the ArcGIS Cache Manager and end that task to regain their toolbar.

[image: TaskManager-ArcGisCacheManager]

I have read extensively about this problem:

1. https://community.esri.com/thread/121214#comment-625142
2. https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012616
3. [ArcMap Add-In Not Updating To Latest Version](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131848/arcmap-add-in-not-updating-to-latest-version)
4. https://community.esri.com/thread/117694

Interestingly, I see mixed results among users with their AssemblyCache folders (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.x\AssemblyCache). The add-in is associated with a GUID, and the folder name for the add-in in the AssemblyCache folder is that GUID. One user's AssemblyCache{GUID} folder updates to contain the latest dlls, and another user's folder is completely empty, always, before or after an update to the add-in.

I would like more information about this problem. Even better, I would like to know if there is an ESRI or Windows setting that can be changed to address this problem, or if that is not an option, is there a way to automate ending the ArcGIS Cache Manager task using ArcObjects inside the source code for our add-in?

Comment: We have many add-ins and from time to time will have to delete assemblycache folder or kill all Arc processes to fix it and I've never found a way around that, and we have a similar set up as you (though on 10.5). 

On thing to look out for is if you have any libraries that other add-ins reference. If another add-in has an older version of a library and it loads first, then the updated library will not be loaded for another add-in unless it is strongly named. This has caused similar problems for some of my add-ins in the past.

Comment: @danielm Thanks! We examined the cache folder and found ESRI dlls, because we had not set the Copy Local properties for the ESRI references to false. We set them to false. However, the toolbar still malfunctions in a mxd that is open when an updated add-in is posted, and the toolbar is gone from a mxd that opens after the update. However, it seems that the ArcGIS Cache Manager does not run when we close ArcMap, AND simply closing all mxds brings the toolbar back, so reboots are no longer required. It seems that this may only happen when a mxd is open and when an updated add-in is posted...?

Comment: I need to remove my assembly cache frequently, on a development environment debugging fails to load symbols until all previous versions are removed. In a user environment the cache fails to get overwritten by newer versions occasionally, located in a central server location which is why I put build dates in my form titles. It's frustrating working with an intermittent problem but as @danielm said I've found no guaranteed solution, perhaps it's time to lodge a ticket with Esri, if they provide an answer that works post it here **please**, there's a few who would be interested to see it.